# Android Window Manager Layout Inflater is not inflating a full screen layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager

I have been attempting to learn Android Java shenanigans, so still very new to it. I managed to get a `Service` working that inflates a layout to create a `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`. The layout is a transparent red, but only takes up the middle part of my screen. My hope was to have it cover and fill the entire screen.

This is what happens:

[image]

Main Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#0092a3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activate"
        android:id="@+id/btnActivate"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:width="100dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Overlay Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#40ff0000">

</LinearLayout>
```

Service Class onCreate method:

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new  WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mTopView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.red_overlay, null);

    windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <service android:name=".Layer" />

    </application>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
</manifest>
```

Everything works great! And I am quite proud of myself for getting this far. Sadly, I cannot figure out why it won't fill the screen. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It figures after I make a post I solve my problem. I just kept searching google and I found this helpful piece of [heaven.](http://www.whycouch.com/2013/01/how-to-overlay-view-over-everything-on.html)

The new and improved Service:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mTopView = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.red_overlay, null);

windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
```

Switched ViewGroup to LinearLayout.

Switched FLAG_FULLSCREEN to MATCH_PARENT. And, Viola.

Comment: I was able to achieve this from an Activity, but still unable to get fullscreen from Service. The statusbar and navigation bar still appears. In the Activity I override the onFocusChanged method, but I have to wait a few seconds till it goes to fullscreen.